# Maclaurin series and taylor

Tags: integration, taylor-expansion

Im trying to find the first four terms  of Maclaurin series of $\space0.15t^2$ and evaluate
$$\int_0^1 e^{-0.15}t^2 dt
$$

Please this is a revision question. How do i go about it?

Comment: $0.15t^2$ is already belongs to a Maclaurin series.

Answer (score 1):

You know the Maclaurin series for $e^s$? Now you can just plug in $s=0.15t^2$. 
Then evaluate the integral as a sum of powers of $t$.